# How can I check if a DVD is genuine?

Tags: 12.04

I have a problem and really need help. I have two DVD's, one of this DVD is burned by me. The other one is a strange DVD from someone else, I do not really know if this DVD is fine...

Both of the DVD supposed to have Ubuntu on it. Now, I do not know which DVD is mine... I mean which I burned by myself. I copied this to DVD to my PC and compared the two respective folders using `cmp`. It showed no difference. Does it mean that I can use any of it for installing Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the title a bit misleading? If you compared both DVDs and they have the same content, then obviously both must be "genuine" as there is no difference. If you can't tell them apart by label, then you might want to look out on properties like the burn/recording dates as suggested below by user wilf.

Answer (score 2):

Just generate a checksum for both DVD's and if they have the same checksum then they contain the same data. If you only want to compare the two disks, then the `md5sum /dev/cdrom` command is enough, run it for both disks. If you want to compare them to the genuine iso, then you will have to read the more [detailed instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#Check_the_CD).

Why this method is better than simply `cmp`-ing the mounted directories:

- `cmp` can only tell whether the 2 disks are identical, it won't help in telling whether they are genuine, whereas `md5sum` helps in the latter case too.
- Comparing the block device files are a much simpler command, than comparing the mounted folders.
- Checksum comparison can be done with only 1 optical drive, whereas comparing by `cmp` needs 2 optical drives.

Comment: Given that he used cmp correctly, how would creating and comparing checksums differ from using `cmp` and telling the media apart if they contain the same data (payload)?

Comment: @LiveWireBT I added some info clarifying why checksumming is the preferred method, IMHO. But you are right, this question could be answered by a simple **YES** too.

Comment: `cmp /dev/sr0 /dev/sr1` will have the same result as computing the `md5sum` for both and can in theory be faster if the files are not equal.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yes, true.

Answer (score 1):

You could just identify when the disk was burned - see [here](https://superuser.com/a/559089/277135).

Basically just run this:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=1 skip=33581 count=17 | hexdump -C
```

*(This will only work if `/dev/sr0` is where the disk is mounted)*

You will get something like this:

```
[wilf@comp ~]$ dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=1 skip=33581 count=17 | hexdump -C
17+0 records in
17+0 records out
17 bytes (17 B) copied00000000  32 30 31 33 31 30 31 36  31 39 31 36 34 32 30 30  |2013101619164200|
00000010  00                                                |.|
, 0.000152142 s, 112 kB/s
00000011
[wilf@comp ~]$
```

Look for the bit like

```
|2013101619164200|
```

So this means that this 13.10 disk I burned for another computer was done on:

2013 November 16th  , at 17:16:42.00

Then you can find the time difference between the disks.

Answer (score 0):

Safe files on the two discs doesn't mean that you can use any of those two install Ubuntu. I mean, the disc you burn yourself may fail to boot successfully. What you need to do is insert those discs one by one and try to boot from those. If they boot safely , they might be the same.
In order to solve your problem I recommend to find the date of burn of the 2 discs.   The answer is [here](https://superuser.com/a/559089/252720).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can install Ubuntu from both the disks. But I am not sure which of those is burned by myself :(

Answer (score 0):

I would try get the information on the DVD-Recorder used for burning the disk. Then you would know for sure!

I do not know if it is possible to access this data from the ISO, similar to identification of the time the disk was burned?